# Request Json data from node.js server in a HTML Page

Tags: json, node.js

I got my `node.js` server to output `MongoDb` data in the browser like this

```
"[
  {"_id":"5575532d38957e14136ac889","masa":"Masa 1","statut":"nou","produse":[]},   
  {"_id":"55755428809ca96419c296ae","masa":"Masa 5","statut":"nou","produse":    
  [{"numeprod":"Espresso","cantitate":"1","pret":"10"},
   {"numeprod":"Late","cantitate":"1","pret":"15"}]},   
   {"_id":"557553ec38957e14136ac88a","masa":"Masa 2","statut":"nou","produse":
   [{"numeprod":"Briose","cantitate":"19","pret":"15"},  
    {"numeprod":"Late","cantitate":"1","pret":"15"},
    {"numeprod":"Espresso","cantitate":"1","pret":"10"},
    {"numeprod":"URSUS","cantitate":"4","pret":"5"}
   ]}
]"
```

How can i decode this `JSON` data and display it in a `HTML` table ?
I'm new to this , and reading other questions on this are not helping 
Thank You

Comment: If you using express with ejs/jade, you response the JSON data and display in a common HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display the data, you have to define the data for the view you want to use it for. Instead of requesting the raw data (what you're getting), store the data in a variable and pass it into a structured html page:

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var file = require('file');
var middleware = function(req, res) {
    res.send(file);
    res.end();
};
http.createServer(middleware).listen(somePort);
```

file.js

```
var db = require('mongodb').MongoClient; // I assume you're using node-mongodb-native
db.connect(mongoURLtoDb, function(err, db) {
    db.collection(yourcollection).find().toArray(function(err, data) {
        var output = "
            //Here you can put whatever HTML markup you want. 
            " + data.key1 + "
            // etc...
        ";
        module.exports = output;
    });
});
```